# Iterating through Environments in Berkeley Database JE

Tags: database, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I am trying to list all existing Database Environments (*com.sleepycat.je.Environment*) in a given instance of Berkeley DB Java Edition.
Cannot find any API or documentation regarding this.

Scanning the subdirectories containing all environments seems a little ugly.
Does anyone know how to do it properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Environment` is defined by its home directory only and there's no structure above it, so your only option is indeed to scan all the directories.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.